# Css href button

Tags: css

What would be the best approach of creating other colors of link buttons, without copying the entire thing again and again.
I already have a blue button.. now i want to have another orange or green button

```
.blue-button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #4479BA;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
.blue-button:hover {
    background: #356094;
    border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.blue-buttonk:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #2E5481;
    border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
```

Comment: Create a base button class with all standard properties like border-radius, padding, box-shadow, user-select etc and additional classes just for the color like [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/e11j97v8/). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Harry - this would be a good answer.

Comment: @misterManSam: Just checking if this is really what OP wanted :)

Comment: @harry - thanks that was perfect- kudos

Comment: @user244394: Welcome mate. Glad to be of help. I am not adding that as answer because there is already another one posted on same lines and I don't want to make it repetitive :)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the color and background from the button and create another class just for the those properties. i.e. .blue and .red

Then you can move those properties inside those classes applying also the :hover and :active selectors.

In case you want to change color, change the html and change the class blue into red.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button blue">Click me</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .button {
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;    
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: solid 1px #20538D;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
        transition-duration: 0.2s;
        -webkit-user-select:none;
        -moz-user-select:none;
        -ms-user-select:none;
        user-select:none;
    }
    .button:hover {
        background: #356094;
        border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        border: solid 1px #203E5F;
    }

    .button.blue{background: #4479BA; color: #FFF;}
    .button.blue:hover{ background: #356094; }
    .button.blue:active { background: #2E5481; }

    .button.red{background: red; color: yellow;}
    .button.red:hover{ background: green; }
    .button.red:active { background: pink; }
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/douv8oby/